# How big is (Breath of the Wild's iteration of) Hyrule?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild has a huge world. I want to impress people by comparing Hyrule's size to that of a real-world location. **Has anyone estimated the size of Hyrule?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The BOTW map is  ~60<sup>2</sup> km or ~37<sup>2</sup> miles.

[This gif/video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIf0j.jpg) makes a size comparison between other LoZ maps (and even Skyrim).

Again, this isn't *exact*, but using measurements in the game (even using Link's height of ~1.7m/5'7"*) we can approximate.

---

<sup>* Again, this is an approximation - [Source](https://characterprofile.fandom.com/wiki/Link_(Breath_of_the_Wild))</sup>

Comment: Hrm, saying "Hyrule is as big as Manhattan" isn't as satisfying as I'd hoped. Well, thank you!